# reference and destructor in c++

Tags: c++, reference, destructor

I have the following class:

```
class A
{
public:
   B& getB() {return b;}    
private:   
    B b;
};

class B
{
   ~B() {cout<<"destructor B is called";}
...

};

void func()
{
   A *a = new a;
   B b = a->getB();
   .....
}
```

Why does the destructor of class B is called when exiting the function func? Doest the function getB return a referance to the object B? if class A still exists at the end of function func, why does the destructor of B is called?

Comment: Your b object is still local to the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have:

```
B b = a->getB();
```

a new object of type `B` is created from a reference to existing instance of `B` (`B&`). It is not the `B::operator=` that is called here but **copy constructor**.

Each class has a copy constructor (if you don't add it explicitly, compiler will provide one for you). It accepts a single argument which is a reference to the same class. You haven't put copy constructor in the code above so I assume that compiler has generated one for you:

```
class B
{
public:
   B(B& other)
   {
      // memberwise copy (shallow copy) 
   };
};
```

So `A::getB()` returned a reference to member `A::b` and this reference was passed as an argument to `B::B(B&)`.

```
void func()
{
   A *a = new A();  // Instance of A is created on the heap;
                    // (pointer a is a local variable and is on the stack though!)
                    // A::b is object of type B and it is on the heap as well  

   B b = a->getB(); // Instance of class B is created on the stack (local variable)
   .....
   delete a;        // deleting A from the heap: 
                    // A::~A is called which calls B::~B (of its member b)
} // a and b go out of the scope; b is an object => B::~B is called
```

Comment: so what use does returning by reference from a function if a new object is created?

Comment: @Shay: The object is returned by reference so it avoisd the copy of object as while in returning by value, but this returned reference is then copied to create a new object on the stack which is then initialized using returned reference.

Answer (score 22):

```
 B b = a->getB();
```

will be calling the copy constructor `B(const& B)` so you are creating a new object on the stack with is a copy of the object returned by the reference.
Use instead:

```
 B& b = a->getB();
```

and no destructor will be called since you won't create a new B object

Comment: A copy of the reference means a copy of the address of B?

Comment: @chaiy don't think so, you'd just call the copy constructor

Comment: @Shay no, this answer is misleading. It means a copy of *the object*.

Comment: Sorry - I didnt understand, If the copy constructor is called, then whats the difference between returning by reference or by value?

Comment: the copy constructor is only called when you assign the returned reference to an actual object, if you assign it to a reference no new object is created

Comment: @lezebulon, sorry I mis-expressed myself, I know your method works fine. But I was guessing shay's original solution will likely cause run time error.